# How to re-find the parent of a dynamically loaded link with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a simple little jquery/ajax pagination script for my Wordpress theme.

So far it's all working until I rebind the click event to the pagination links. The reason I'm reloading the pagination bar itself is because it changes position and appearance on every page (eg.. on the first page it's 1, 2, 3 ... 6 - and on the third page it's 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).

What happens after I rebind the click is, when the new pagination bar is clicked, it reloads itself once but not the content. And if I click the pagination bar a third time, it doesn't work at all.

I think what is happening is that when I rebind the click event, my selectors no longer work. Because my selectors inside the main function do things like find the parent of the pagination bar and the children. So my question is... is that the issue and how does one go about finding the parent etc of a dynamically loaded link like that?

I've added some comments to the code to help you read it. Thanks in advance for any help!

```html
// This is the initial click event listener
    $(".paginationInner a, .paginationInner span").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        paginationClick($(this));
    });
    
    
    // This is the function I use to rebind the new pagination links to the click event
    function bindPaginationClick(obj){
        $paginateLinks = obj.find("a");
        $paginateLinks.bind("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            paginationClick($(this));
        });
    }
        
    // This is the main function, the one that reloads the pagination bar and content
    function paginationClick(obj){
        // These are my selectors for finding the different elements I need to get all this working.
        $paginationBarInner = obj.parent(".paginationInner");
        $paginateLinks = $paginationBarInner.find("a");
        $paginationBar = $paginationBarInner.parent(".paginationParent");
        $parentObj = $paginationBar.parent(".recentList");
        $parentObjInner = $parentObj.children(".recentListInner");
        
        var originalurl = window.location.href;
        
        // This is irrelevant to my question, it's just to figure out the href to be loaded in.
        if (obj.tagName == 'SPAN' && obj.hasClass("dots") ) {
            return false;
        } else if ( obj.tagName == 'SPAN' ){
            var link = originalurl;         
        } else {
            var link = obj.attr('href');
        }
        
        // Here I unbind the original pagination links, because they will disappear.
        $paginateLinks.unbind("click");
        
        // Here I hide the original pagination bar
        $paginationBarInner.hide("fast", function(){    
            // Then reload the new pagination bar from the href specified in the if statement above.    
            $paginationBarInner.load(link + ' .paginationInner', function() {
                // Here I show the new pagination bar.
                $paginationBarInner.show();
                // Here I send the new pagination bar to the rebind function.
                bindPaginationClick($paginationBarInner);
            });
        });

        
        // Here I'm hiding the content while it reloads.
        // This is the part that doesn't work when the new pagination bar is clicked.
        $parentObjInner.animate({opacity:0}, function(){
            // Here I'm just scrolling back to where the user will need to be.
            $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
                    scrollTop: $parentObj.offset().top
            }, 2000);
            
            // Here I'm loading in the new content.
            $parentObjInner.load(link + ' .recentListInner', function() {
                // Here I'm showing the new content.
                $parentObjInner.animate({opacity:1});
            });
            
        }); 
        
    }
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit as to where you render the pagination? Is that part of a library or? I would personally just set a click event on the pagination buttons directly after creating them and rerender the entire thing. No need to unbind. There should  exist a function from the pagination index to the location right?

Comment: No it's not a library, I don't really know how to do those. What I'm doing is loading that jquery code into this parent script:

`(function($) { // Begin jQuery
  $(function() { // DOM ready`

As for the pagination bar itself, that's being rendered into the php page template. I did think of trying to bind them within the page but I'm a bit afraid of doing that too because I use a caching plugin that reorganises the way my JS loads. I thought I should probably get it all working in the same script so that it's all in one place to begin with.

Comment: Well either the pagination bar is managed by your PHP, or by your javascript. I wouldnt recommend mixing that up. Maybe you can expiriment with not rendering the pagination bar in PHP and purely render it through javacript so you're in control. Besides that advice (which could be wrong) I don't think I have an idea how to help. I stay away from WordPress

Comment: Wordpress can get a bit annoying at times for sure. As for the rendering of the pagination bar, it is all done in PHP. After those pages are cached they're all HTML pages with the pagination bar on each one. What I'm doing with the jQuery is just grabbing the pagination bar from say 'page 2' and then loading that onto page 1. So the jQuery itself is not constructing the pagination bar for me, only fetching it from a different page. The pagination bar from the different page has all the same links etc.. it's just that I don't think jQuery can find the parent elements of that new dynamic bar.

Comment: I guess I just didn't understand your problem. Thankfully someone else did ;) Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding  `>` to your `load()` selector so you aren't nesting `.paginationInner` inside itself.

The following simple example demonstrates the issue

```js
const fakePage = `<div id="foo">
                     <div class="fakeInner">
                       <div>New Stuff</div>
                     </div>
                  </div>`;

$.fn.fakeLoad=function(selector, callback){
  $(this).html( $(fakePage).find(selector)  );
  callback.apply(this)
};

$('button').click(function(){

   let selector = '.fakeInner';
   if(this.id==='2'){
        selector += ' >'
   }

  $('.fakeInner').fakeLoad(selector, function(){
      console.clear()
      console.log($('#fake').html())
  })
})
```

```css
.fakeInner{ border: 1px solid green; padding:1em}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="1">Fake Load 1</button><button id="2">Fake Load 2</button>
<div id="fake">
  <div class="fakeInner">
    Blah Blah
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah thank you! Such a silly mistake. Yes you're right, I was loading .paginationInner into itself. I didn't quite do it your way but I just changed the load line to `$paginationBar.load(link + ' .paginationInner', function() {` and that works. Thanks!

Comment: Should also be able to delegate the event listeners to `$paginationBar` also if it never gets replaced